# how to delete load balancer using gcloud command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcloud, resource-cleanup

Deleting load balancer from [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/loadBalancers/list) is easy. Just click on delete icon and wait for the load balancer to disappear.

Is there similar `gcloud` command to delete load balancer (cascade delete all related frontend, backend, url-map, health check etc. )?

[GCP Documents](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/) explain how to setup various load balancers but none of them cover how to clean up

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no single `gcloud` command to wipe out a loadbalancer. You'll need to delete its constituent parts, one at a time.

These parts are:

Backend

```
gcloud compute backend-services delete [BACKEND_SERVICE]
```

Target Proxy

```
gcloud compute target-${PROTOCOL}-proxies delete [TARGET_PROXY]
```

Forwarding Rules (Frontend)

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules delete [FORWARDING_RULE]
```

Static IP addresses

```
gcloud compute addresses delete [IP_ADDRESS]
```

Health Checks

```
gcloud compute health-checks delete [HEALTH_CHECK]
```

URL Maps

```
gcloud compute url-maps delete [URL_MAP]
```

Depending on your needs, you may or may not want to actually delete your static IPs and health checks, or even have any URL maps to delete.

Comment: I had to delete in the order: forwarding rule, target-proxy, url map and then backend service. As it complained about dependencies otherwise.

Comment: what about certificates?

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful to delete orphaned resources:

https://github.com/pantheon-systems/kube-gce-cleanup